# We want to have utility to tigger test cases on a machine with TestNG with some java code

Tags: testng

I have tests of TestNG with Java code and want to run those on native machine with CMD command or bat file.

Can it done using Java or not?

Answer (score 1):

Check [the manual](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng). It will be something like:

```
java org.testng.TestNG testng1.xml [testng2.xml testng3.xml ...
```